# Make div fill height but not extend it (use scrollbar for overflow)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a specific layout that I want to achieve on my web page, namely:
[image]

The layout in the above image is built with the following HTML and bootstrap classes:

```
        <div className="ContentWrapper d-flex mh-100 flex-row h-100">
            <div className="ContentBody flex-column flex-fill">
                <div className="ContentHeader p-3 w-100">
                    <h2>Header</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="ContentMain w-100">
                    <h2>Scrollable div, should fill height, but not more than that</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="Sidebar h-100">
                <h2>Sidebar content</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.ContentWrapper {
    background-color: red;
}

.ContentBody {
    background-color: blue;
}

.ContentHeader {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.ContentMain {
    background-color: purple;
    flex: 1;
}

.Sidebar {
    background-color: green;
    width: 500px;
}
```

However, when there is too much content in the purple part, the component starts to increase in height. I wish to prevent that and have a scrollbar in the purple component.

Furthermore, I heard that some flex properties work different in Chrome and Firefox. The idea is that I want my web page to have the same behavior in both browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `h-100` on `ContentWrapper` and add `height: 100vh` to it. Make your `ContentBody` a flexbox by adding `d-flex- class. See demo below with explanations:

```css
.ContentWrapper {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh; /* ADDED */
}

.ContentBody {
  background-color: blue;
}

.ContentHeader {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.ContentMain {
  background-color: purple;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto; /* ADDED */
}

.Sidebar {
  background-color: green;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="ContentWrapper d-flex mh-100 flex-row"> <!-- removed h-100 class -->
  <div class="ContentBody d-flex flex-column flex-fill"> <!-- added d-flex class -->
    <div class="ContentHeader p-3 w-100">
      <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="ContentMain w-100">
      <h2>Scrollable div, should fill height, but not more than that</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Sidebar h-100">
    <h2>Sidebar content</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can consider the bootstrap classes (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-viewport / https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/overflow/)

Answer (score 0):

Just find already have an answer there...
Whatever put the codepen i just finished, which i think it is a more flexbox way.

```
<div class="ContentWrapper d-flex mh-100 flex-row h-100">
  <div class="ContentBody flex-column flex-fill d-flex">
    <div class="ContentHeader p-3 w-100">
      <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="ContentMain w-100 flex-fill overflow-auto">
      <h2>Scrollable div
    </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Sidebar h-100 flex-shrink-0">
    <h2>Sidebar content</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/ramseyfeng/pen/drWNYQ